# adjust annotation view frame while drawing path using google cordinates

Tags: ios, mkannotationview

I set image in Annotation View. and put two difference annotation with path between that two pin then annotation view frame not adjust properly. i want that annotation bottom part touch at start of the path and end of the path.

I tried to use native pin it place at perfect place. so how can i set proper frame for custom annotation view.

Answer (score 0):

i got solution i set center offset like this.

customAnnotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-10, -10);